# How to restrict files to being moved to another folder in win10?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, restriction

Good day, I need to find out a way how **to disable** for **win10** **user to move** specific **file** or files **from specific folder**. How this can be done for example with **batch script code** or there is another way how to do it? I appreciate to see solution ***in any program language***, that can help me with.

Another obstacle would be, what if **I want to restrict to move files from system folders** like "C:\Windows\System32" path which is under administrator rights, and I suppose the person I will restrict can use those rights and move files.

I suppose too, that **files** I want to restrict to move, **will OS often use** and I won't to disable access to that files even for operation system, or any software in pc that needs it. Or another example, if you want to restrict hosts file to move, but browser would often look into it on startup or when hosts file content changed.

I did not actually find anything relevant, but only how to lock folder, but I think that's not the thing I need. Is it possible to do it, to restrict system files being moved? Do I need to work with Registry Editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to solve this by writing a program, I think the tool you are looking for is `icacls` (part of win10).

The docs for this command are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls

If you aren't looking to do a ton at once, however, I recommend right-clicking on the file and choosing "Properties" from the menu. From there, click on the "Security" tab. This will give you a way to change permissions on a file or directory by hand.
More instructions for the manual solution here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325361/how-to-configure-security-for-files-and-folders-on-a-network-in-window#2

Comment: Ok, fine, thanks for contribution ... but as I see, in the first link it is just a way how to do the same things as in another .. I will just disable inheritance with copy and after that restrict user ... but ok, the same user I restricted can go here and through security options just restore permissions and enable inheritance ... I see I need some kind of option how to just lock it before user at all points of view... for example with password.. it can be done somehow ? (with code or UI)

Comment: Yeah, so I (currently am on mac, but) remember being able to change a specific preference for who has access to the security preferences of the files. You're absolutely right that a user could edit the preferences and give themselves access to a folder, I used to do it in middle school all the time. In the same menu for changing the security preferences it should have an option of which users/groups have access to the security preferences themselves.

Comment: I understand, of course it is obvious, that user can change those preferences and access rights, but user cannot dispose of his own rights like an administrator (if I want to restrict access to the security preferences it wrote I have no rights to do so even like an admin), if I understand, user cannot make system inconsistent and lock something before yourself forever... just I can make new user account on PC that I can restrict from upper administrator account, but that is not the way I am looking for ... maybe if someone would like to change sec. pref. it could ask password ... that I need